# how transaction work in sequelize node js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Just need a simple and proper explanation how
In `sequelize.transaction()` how does this transaction: t work?

```
sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
    {
    transaction : t,
    }
}
```

need simple explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see a lot of examples here https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html.

TL; DR; You just need to pass the transaction object to the every call you make.